# play a .m4a file from iPod Music Library using avaudioplayer

Tags: iphone, ios, export, avaudioplayer, m4a

Does anyone know how to play a selected .m4a file from the iPhone's iPod music library using a AVAudioPlayer? Is it possible to either export or copy the file to local Documents directory of the iPhone? Can anyone share any sample code to successfully handle this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using the avaudioplayer to play music from your music library is not possible. Nor is there a way to copy files from the music library to the local path of your app. 
If you use the avplayer you can access the music library.

Comment: Actually, this is not correct.  I have been able to play mp3 files from my music library without any problem.  However I get an error "The operation couldn't be completed (OSStatus error -43.)" when I attempt to play an m4a file.   To get it to work with mp3 files, I used the MPMediaPickerController to select a file from my music library.  In the didPickMediaItems callback method, you can get the song URL from the MPMediaItem(s) and use this URL in AVAudioPlayer initWithContentsOfURL.